# How to make a spinner work?

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image]Hey guys I'm new to spinners, and for some reason when I click on the spinner, I can't get a dropdown menu. Do I need to have something inside the onItemSelected method for it to drop down?

here is some basic code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Spinner dropDownspinner;
    private ArrayAdapter menuAdapter;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
         //spinner
        dropDownspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        menuAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Drop_Down_Menu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        dropDownspinner.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        dropDownspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
   }
}
```

STRING ARRAY:

```
<!--Main Spinner-->
<string name="Profile">Profile</string>
<string name="Friends">Friends </string>
<string name="Folders">Folders</string>
<string name="Edit">Setting</string>
<string-array name="Drop_Down_Menu">
    <item></item>
</string-array>
```

In my layout.

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a spinner `function` eg. `addItemsOnSpinner();` in your `onCreateView`.Then add

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Profiles");
        list.add("Friends");
        list.add("Folder");
        list.add("Setting");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the solution. I do have another question, so when do the spinner, do you know how you make sure when you click on the spinner, the first item doesn't popup where you had clicked the spinner but instead the first item pop up right underneath where you initially clicked the spinner, if that makes sense?

Comment: did my answer solved your first question?  I didn't get what you  mean

Comment: Yes it did. So I added a picture above to describe my next question. So when i click on menu, it shows up constantly where I press the spinner. I want the word "menu" or the "menu" tab to be directly underneath where i clicked menu.

Comment: I'm not really know how to solve your next question . Maybe you can post your next question in another post?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to have something inside the onItemSelected method for it to drop down?

No, but you do have to call `setDropDownViewResource()` on the `SpinnerAdapter` to say what the drop-down entries should look like:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.selection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity
  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
  private TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
          "sit", "amet",
          "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
          "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
          "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
          "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

    Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                              items);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    selection.setText("");
  }
}
```